# Redirect nice urls to filtered urls (/products/attr/value -> /products.html?attr=valueid)

Tags: attributes, redirect, routing

Normally attribute filters create links such as:

```
/products.html?brand=3
```

I'd like to have links such as this work:

```
/products/brand/MannCo
```

I don't want to hardcode these links and don't want the user to ever see the uglier link, so would the best solution be a custom module/controller? I'm having trouble figuring out how to setup the routing...

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how you would implement a solution for this yourself but i've used http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus a few times and solves the majority of issues with layered navigation.